# Bitrix24 Framework

Tags: json, rest

Buenas tardes,
quería saber si alguien trabajó con este Framework alguna vez.
Necesito saber cómo poder realizar las llamadas REST para obtener el Json y poder trabajar a partir de esto.
Muchas gracias.
Saludos.